# add order by to query formula that gets unique list and count from delimited strings in a column Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a formula that gets a unique list of titles from pipe-delimited string in a column and there counts

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("|",Elements!$H2:$H),"|")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))
```

I need to sort the counts in a descending manor, I have tried adding `order by Col2 Desc`

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("|",Elements!$H2:$H),"|")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) order by Col2 Desc''",0))
```

But I get unable to parse ...

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("|", Elements!H2:H), "|")&{"";""}),
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col2) desc
  label count(Col2)''", 0))
```

Comment: Thank you player0 that sorted it! (not allowed to accept your answer for 10 minutes)